# Connotations behind 可愛げのない態度?

Tags: translation, meaning, usage, nuances, slang

I thought 可愛げのない態度 came to the simple translation of 'charmless attitude', but on a whim I searched up the phrase, and in daily life context it seems more like 'having a cold attitude' than acting in an uncute way. Then I happened upon a translation where someone translated it as 'having no further intentions' which really just confused me more.

Am I to take 可愛げのない態度 at face value and understand it as an attitude OTHERS do not find endearing, or should there be extra connotations for it being a cold and uninterested attitude the doer themself is showing others, if only in dating scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is difficult to explain.

I think "charmless attitude" is basically correct.
But, if you want to know further you should look into the word, 可愛げのない.
If you check a thesaurus, you find it is rather "devious or indirect (性格が素直でない)." It is not about appearance, but a spirit.
http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E5%8F%AF%E6%84%9B%E3%81%92%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84

We do not call a devious politician *可愛げのない政治家 because we do not expect a politician is adorable.

So, typically a child, supposed to be biddable, could be 可愛げのない. For example, you want to do some favour for him/her, but s/he does not accept it thinking "You cannot trick me."
I think this is the most typical 可愛げのない.

Also, new hires can be 可愛げのない. They are supposed to ask for help. But, they may refuse.

Dating is basically giving and accepting favours and offers.
In dating scenarios,
可愛げのない can be liberally translated to "no further intentions" because people sometimes refuse to accept offers to show they have no further intentions. But, sometimes, it is just because they are not used to it, or shy.

Comment: This occurred to me just now, would the same connotations apply with other structures too? For example, does the connotation of being uncooperative/closed off apply to comments like 可愛げはない or 可愛げがない as well, or does that connotation only apply to the のない stucture?

Comment: 可愛げはない、可愛げがない and 可愛げのない are basically the same. Yet, 可愛げはない sounds like there is something else instead.